# android TextView make invisible span on Kindle Fire

Tags: android, android-emulator, invisible, kindle-fire, spannablestring

I want to have a portion of my TextView invisible. In detail, I present a math problem to the user:

`9 * 9 = 81`

and I want `81` to be invisible. As user types correct answer, I make digit "8" and then "1" visible.

I tried to use `TextAppearanceSpan` and `ForegroundColorSpan` with transparent color (both **#00000000** and **Color.TRANSPARENT**) and they work perfectly for every device and emulator except KindleFire device and emulator.

On Kindle Fire, "81" appears colored in sort-of-dark-grey. It seems that rasterizer tries to make it invisible against some "sort-of-dark-grey" background, not against background (which looks like grid paper image) that I've set in the root `LinearLayout` of my `Activity`.

[image]

My question is: how can I make a portion of text in `TextView` invisible using neither `TextAppearanceSpan` nor `ForegroundColorSpan`? Does there exist another "span" that measures text correctly, but does not paint it?

**Update**

I've discovered that there exist some mysterous `RasterizerSpan` and `MetricAffectingSpan`, which could (judging by the title) help.

As I can see, the only meaning of RasterizerSpan is to set a Rasterizer to the TextPaint object:

```
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
    ds.setRasterizer(mRasterizer);
}
```

I found it promising: if I were able to set a kind of "void" rasterizer (that just does nothing), it would make this text invisible. Unfortunately

```
new RasterizerSpan(null); // (set mRasterizer to null)
```

did not help.

My another idea is to implement a custom ShaderSpan that would set a "void" shader:

```
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
    ds.setShader(myCustomVoidShader);
}
```

but I do not understand how to create a shader that produces "nothing".

Comment: what happens on kindle fire if you set whole TextViews TextColor transparent?

Comment: extend ForegroundColorSpan & override updateDrawState & do not call super method in that

Comment: >what happens on kindle fire if you set whole TextViews TextColor transparent

it works fine (it is invisible).

Comment: 2Satya: super's method is ds.setColor(mColor). If I don't call it, color remains unchanged (=black). It will not be transparent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See if overriding `updateDrawState()` on your `ForegroundColorSpan` and calling [setXferMode()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#setXfermode%28android.graphics.Xfermode%29) will work:

```
public class TransparentSpan extends ForegroundColorSpan {
    private final PorterDuffXfermode MODE = new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST);

    public TransparentSpan(int color) {
        super(color);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
        super.updateDrawState(ds);
        ds.setXfermode(MODE);
    }
}
```

Sorry, I didn't have a Kindle Fire to test with :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use AbsoluteSizeSpan, set the size to 0. So it will invisible

span = new AbsoluteSizeSpan(0, true);
spannableString.setSpan(span, wordPosition.start, wordPosition.end, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

Notice:
The next word of the invisible word will take place the invisible word position.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using the android visibility (true or false). It will do the same job you need (or there is a specificreason you would lie to use Span) ?